# Old Mobile Agents

Tags: mobile, detect, agent

I have a responsive website and I have a problem with old devices!
I want to design a basic web page for mobile users,therefor, I need to detect old moblies firt,so I need old mobile agents!
Finally I want a compelete list of old mobile agents

**if every body has a regex code I'll be glad to have it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

https://deviceatlas.com/

etc etc. Wurful is probably the one to go for as they have a public version of their data.

There's no "this is old" tag however.